# Navigate to specific group header in grouped GridView (win store app)

Tags: windows, xaml, gridview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I want to make something like when I'm choosing some item from a ComboBox so that my grouped GridView that located into ScrollViewer will nevigate/focus to the group (or to its header) that has the group-header with the string value of the chosen item in the ComboBox.

Any ideas? mayble some games with TabIndex property or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you host Grid View inside of ScrollViewer? GridView has it is own ScrollViewer.
2. When you will start to use ScrollViewer inside of GridView (just move Grid View out of ScrollViewer) - you just need to use [ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242911.aspx) method to navigate to the item.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this one out, and update you. Seems promising.